# Can you let me know: Are the ERC-20 smart contracts that are made by "euruz.xyz" Dapp on Trust Wallet are trusted?

Tags: scam

The smart contract address is:
0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7
The contract has transferred my 2,269 USDT to the address: 0x35780d50188F92B327EfdAf154685B68425AB57c
& the Customer Service of "euruz.xyz" said that:" My 2,269 USDT is blocked for 360 days"
The DApp "euruz.xyz" is still working in Trust Wallet,so that, your answers are very much useful for many other investors!

English transalation found on google:

Smart contract address: 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7
They blocked my 2,269 USDT & said they would return it after 360 days.

Comment: Please reach out to Euruz.xyz support team, as this seems to be sketchy and not a reputed site.

Comment: Thank DevCrypto very much !

Comment: Could you check the ERC-20 smart contracts of euruz.xyz DAap are realiable to invest in,sine I don't believe in the Customer Service of euruz.xyz. They always say that:"...my 2,269 USDT are blocked for 360 days."

Answer (score 0):

[![enter[image] ima

1. List item

ge description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV0o2.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV0o2.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV0o2.png): https://i.stack## Heading ##.imgur.com/dFoGG.png## Heading ##
I has used VirusTotal to check "euruz.xyz" and see: there are 9/93 Security vendors analysis say that "euruz.xyz" is Malicious!
Do you think/know those Security vendors analysis ' conclusions are exact ?